# Why I can't scrape Indiegogo although I am using the right xpath?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Here the code I am using to scrape an Indiegogo project but I get nothing:

```
url = 'https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/red-dot-watch'
page = requests.get(url=url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
pledged = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[16]/div[1]/span[1]/span/span[2]/span[1]/text()')
if(len(pledged) > 0):
    print(pledged[0])
else:
    print("MISSING")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ron said, Indiegogo is rendering its contents mostly via JavaScript, and simply requesting the page with Requests does not do that.

Happily, though, the structure of the Indiegogo pages may make it even easier for you to scrape things; there's a `gon.campaign={...}` JavaScript statement that seems to contain the data you're looking for. You should be able to use a regexp in the vein of `gon.campaign=(\{.+\});gon` to extract the data, then parse it as JSON.

**EDIT:** Here's an example - should work until Indiegogo decides to change their layout.

```
import re
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/red-dot-watch'
resp = requests.get(url)
resp.raise_for_status()
m = re.search(r'gon\.campaign=(\{.+?\});gon', resp.text)
if m:
    data = json.loads(m.group(1))
else:
    data = {}

print(data.get('balance'), '/', data.get('target_goal'))
```

Comment: thank you but where should I add the line of code you mentioned? If it's possible for you, could you please give me the piece of code that outputs the pledged amount? Do I need to import any specific package?

Comment: can I use the same method for scraping project URLs from Indiegogo?

Answer (score 2):

Because your script is not parsing JS, thus you are not seeing the same webpage you get generated in your browser.